# Change div appearence on another site on link click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Got a big problem i ran into. I have an index.html with let's say 5 links and a 
*moreinformations.html* with some divs which are `display:none`.

If i click on one of the link at the *index.html* it should forward me to the *moreinformations.html* with displaying the corresponding div ( change css to `display:block`).

How do i do this can i actually send some value from the link to the other html page? I am really confused and hope somebody can help!

Comment: Just a suggestion: you could use PHP to send the data over with the div id being the parameter and then set the display to block based on the received id.

Comment: You have to use PHP to do what you want. You can use javascript: you could open the URL : moreinformations.html#div1 and detect which div to show.

Comment: Can you update the link to include a querystring? e.g. `<a href="moreinformation.html?div=1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this with PHP but since you marked this question jquery, here is a javascript solution. suppose you gave a url parameter and send it using a link like this:

`<a href='moreinformations.html?divid=1'>div1</a>`
`<a href='moreinformations.html?divid=2'>div2</a>`
`<a href='moreinformations.html?divid=3'>div3</a>`

and in moreinformations.html add this js:

```
var queryParams = location.search.substring(1).split("=");
var divid = queryParams[1];
$('#mydiv' + divid).show();
```

and your html might look like:

```
<div id='mydiv1' style='display:none'></div>
<div id='mydiv2' style='display:none'></div>
<div id='mydiv3' style='display:none'></div>
```

Comment: I don't even know what to say! This works perfectly! Thanks alot!

Comment: don't say anything just accept this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the link to include a hash tag e.g. `<a href="moreinformation.html#div1">`

In JS on moreinformation.html you can do the following:

```
$(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash; // hash => #div1
    if (hash) {
            $(hash).show(); // $('#div1').show() - show div with id="div1"
    }
});
```